# .NET Core 3.1 add prefix to all routes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Our institution will only allow us one domain name (foo.bar.edu), so all of our websites are forced to be like this `https://foo.bar.edu/Website1`

I have a .NET Core 3.1 project, I am trying to get it to start on that site.

If I add this to the Configure, it will work, but also the default path will work.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UsePathBase("/Website1");
```

so now `http://localhost:5000/Website1` works, but also `http://localhost:5000` works too.

How can I disable `http://localhost:5000` from working? Only paths that have `/Website1` should work.

The real reason for this is to test production easily since production must be `foo.bar.edu/Website1/route/Index`

Comment: Is your site hosted within IIS? Or some other web-server (or reverse-proxy)? If so, is it using an IIS Application Scope?

Comment: You can try redirecting something like app.MapWhen(context => !context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/Website1"), rootApp =>
    {
        rootApp.Run(async context =>
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("/Website1");
        });
    });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like below :

```
Public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    

    app.UseRouting();

    app.Map("/api", ConfigureApiRoutes); // Add a prefix to all routes


    

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers(); // Other middleware configuration
        // Other endpoint mappings
    });
}

private static void ConfigureApiRoutes(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        // Configure routes specific to the "/api" prefix
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "api_default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        
        // Other endpoint mappings specific to the "/api" prefix
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, if you want to disable the default path, I suggest you could consider using custom middleware.

You could build a custom middleware to disable all the path which is not start with the Website1.

More details, you could refer to below codes example:

```
             app.Use((context, next) =>
            {
                string s = context.Request.Path;
              
 (!context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/Website1"))
                {
                  
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }

                return next();
            });
            app.UsePathBase("/Website1");
```

Also you could consider using the asp.net core url rewrite middleware to redirect from / to /Website1.

More details about how to use url rewrite middleware, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-3.1).